# TinyMCE adding multiple custom toolbar button

Tags: tinymce

I'm following the tutorial on http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/custom_toolbar_button.php  but need to add multiple custom buttons.

Here is my block for adding one button, but I need to add more than one button and don't know how

```
setup : function(fn) {
    // Add a custom button
    fn.addButton('firstname', {
        title : 'Member First Name',
        image : 'resources/scripts/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/img/firstname.gif',
        onclick : function() {
            // Add you own code to execute something on click
            fn.focus();
            fn.selection.setContent('{firstname}');
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 9):

Just call fn.addButton multiple times:

```
setup : function(fn) {
    // Add a custom button
    fn.addButton('firstname', {
        title : 'Member First Name',
        image : 'resources/scripts/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/img/firstname.gif',
        onclick : function() {
            // Add you own code to execute something on click
            fn.focus();
            fn.selection.setContent('{firstname}');
        }
    });
    fn.addButton('lastname', {
        title : 'Member Last Name',
        image : 'resources/scripts/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/img/lastname.gif',
        onclick : function() {
            // Add you own code to execute something on click
            fn.focus();
            fn.selection.setContent('{lastname}');
        }
    });
}
```

If you are defining the `toolbar` layout, eg

```
toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | firstname",
```

remember to add the new `id` (eg. `lastname`)

Comment: Thanks a lot Dr. Molle,
I was thinking something more difficult. Your answer helped me a lot!