# tincyMCE add multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4, django-tinymce

I am trying to add multiple buttons in TinyMce Editor. 
I tried this link [TinyMCE adding multiple custom toolbar button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982613/tinymce-adding-multiple-custom-toolbar-button) and have it in below jsfiddle. This code generates only one button.

jsfiddle.net/LJWcz/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed adding the second to toolbar:

```
toolbar: "mybutton mysecondbutton",
```

[Toolbar](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3atoolbar):

> This controls what buttons you want show up in the toolbar.